# Casablanca alone for 4-5 hours alone . middle aged woman

Tags: safety, casablanca

Marocc Air just changed my flights and now I have an 8 hours lay over in Casa Blanca.  Is it safe to take train to city tour for 4 hours and come back?  Advice please.  I have never been to Morocco